# SimpleXML: get child nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<items>
<aaa>
</aaa>
<aaa>
</aaa>
<aaa>
    <bbb>
    </bbb>
    <bbb>
    </bbb>
    <bbb>
        <ccc>
            Only this childnod what I need
        </ccc>
        <ccc>
            And this one
        </ccc>
    </bbb>
</aaa>
</items>
```

I want parse the XML as given above with PHP. I don't know how to get these two child nodes.

When I use the code below, it triggers the error: `Warning: main() [function.main]: Cannot add element bbb number 2 when only 0 such elements exist in`

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('2.xml');
    foreach ($xml->aaa[2]->bbb as $bbb){
        echo $bbb[2]->$ccc; // wrong in here
        echo $bbb[3]->$ccc;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to use the return of simplexml, but from what I have seen from your code, this should work:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('2.xml');
echo $xml->aaa[2]->bbb[2]->ccc[0];
echo $xml->aaa[2]->bbb[2]->ccc[1];
?>
```

Comment: thanks this works, but do u know why it can not pass in a foreach stuff working?

Comment: You did mix up with the elements. See the comment of imoda.

Answer (score 6):

Use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

```
$ccc = $xml->xpath('aaa/bbb/ccc');
foreach($ccc as $c){
    echo (string)$c."<br/>";
}
```

Result:

```
Only this childnod what I need 
And this one
```

Also, in your initial attempt, `$bbb[3]` does not make sense because you have three items only, starting with index 0.

Answer (score 4):

A more dynamic solution

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('2.xml');
    foreach ($xml->aaa as $aaa){
        if ($aaa->bbb) {
            foreach ($aaa->bbb as $bbb) {
                if ($bbb->ccc)
                    foreach ($bbb->ccc as $ccc) {
                        echo $ccc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks two. more working, maybe I should `count` the `$ccc` child nod, then `break` and `echo out` what I need.