# XML tag count in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<videos>
    <video>
        <title1>Title1</title1>
        <title2>Title2</title2>
        <title3>Title3</title3>
        <title4>Title4</title4>
        <desc> desc</desc>
        <img> img</img>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title1>Title1</title1>
        <title2>Title2</title2>
        <title3>Title3</title3>
        <desc> desc</desc>
        <img> img</img>
    </video>

    <video>
        <title1>Title1</title1>
        <title2>Title2</title2>
        <title3>Title3</title3> 
        <title4>Title3</title4> 
        <title5>Title3</title5>
        <desc> desc</desc>
        <img> img</img>
    </video>
</videos>
```

I have this type of xml. I want to count titles into one video tag.

also want to create text slide show. How can i do it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php function `count` will work. and there is no need in digits added to the `<title>` tag. + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918870/simplexml-get-child-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start using `SimpleXML` to parse the xml, and just use `count()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/xmlfile.xml');
foreach($xml->video as $video) {
    $titles = $video->xpath('./*[contains(name(), "title")]');
    // $titles = $video->xpath('./*[substring(name(), 1, 5) = "title"]');
    $count = count($titles);
    echo $count .'<br/>';
    foreach($titles as $title) {
        echo $title , ' ';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I want to count only title1,title2

Comment: @BhumiShah whats the expected output?